# Java parse value from XML <tag><value/></tag>

Tags: java, xml

I am able to parse something like this:

```
<tag>value</tag>
```

via:

```
File inputFile = new File("input.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("tag");
String value = nodes.getLength() > 0 ? nodes.item(0).getTextContent().trim() : "";
System.out.println(value);  // prints 'value'
```

I tried several things, but I am not able to successfully parse 'value' from this:

```
<tag><value/></tag>
```

It seems to be valid XML, but I don't know what this format is or how to parse the value.

Any suggestions are welcome!

**EDIT:**

From the comments, it looks like `<value/>` is just another tag within `<tag>`. To get 'value' I have to get the child tags name:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("tag");
String value = nodes.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName();
```

Is there a name for a value in this format (one in <> markers ending in /)?

Comment: Are you saying there are tags in the XML that you don't know the name of?

Comment: But you don't have a text content inside this xml `<tag><value/></tag>`, you have only another tag !.

Comment: I am saying I've come across this XML that has the value that's in this format: <VALUE/>. What exactly is it called when the value ends in / and is in <> tags and how can I parse it

Comment: Halayem, thanks for pointing out that <value/> is another tag. So to get 'value' I have to get the tag's name.

Comment: Caution: `nodes.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)` will return the `<value/>` element for your input example, but if the input were `<tag> <value/> </tag>`, it would not.  The space characters are considered child nodes!  Use [Element.getElementsByTagName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName-java.lang.String-) to guarantee your NodeList only contains element children.

Answer (score 0):

To get the node name `value` inside the node `<tag>`, do as follow:

```
   System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeName());
```

To get the text content of value do as follow (`<tag><value>5</value></tag>`):

```
System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```